# Cleanest way to self resize navigation menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this [menu](http://jsfiddle.net/dasmikko/jAptc/), and I want the menu items automatically have the same size, depending on how many menu items there are and the `nav` width.

But I'm having a hard time making this work in a clean way as possible.

[The Menu (JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dasmikko/jAptc/)

This is how I build my menu

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean as clean as possible? Is it working? If so, SO is not for code reviews. Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Otherwise, you should reword your question to something like "How can I avoid hard coding widths for fluid menu?"

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because the habit of providing jsfiddle should be followed by all

Comment: It's not working, but I can see I explained my question in a bad way. I updated my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this if jQuery is an option:

```
$('nav ul > li').css('width',($('nav').width()/$('nav ul > li').size()) +'px');
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jAptc/6/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding right from the first child(ul>li:first-child) and add the below jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var perc = 100 /$('nav>ul>li').length;
    $('nav>ul>li').css("width",perc+"%");
});
```

Basically I'm doing the same logic implemented in ghego1's code except this is in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this way:

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)